# vs.net 2010 Solution Explorer for MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

It is a PIA to find related project files in asp.net-mvc projects. Views / controllers / scripts / models are all scattered around different projects and folders. Productivity Tools->Solution Navigator add-on does not help neither. Do you know an extension /add-on, to help ease the pain of navigating thru mvc projects.

Comment: I use ReSharper's Ctrl+Shift+T and type a filename, and the autocomplete list below narrows down. Thats how I navigate around. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (R#) excels at this.

Ctrl + N gives you a find box where you can quick filter on type.

Ctrl + Shift + N does likewise for file names.

If you can't get R# try adding a short cut for the visual studio EDIT | Navigate to box

ps - I do not get a commission from R#

Comment: I do not have Resharper. It does not sound like it would help a lot for MVC project navigation.

Comment: i couldn't imagine not having it for project navigation, and I work with Mvc all the time.  If you can't get R# try adding a short cut for the visual studio EDIT | Navigate to box

Comment: Looks like 'Navigate To' Ctrl+, is the best alternative.